# Declaring variables in variables with MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables

Is it possible with **MySQL** to create variables depending on other variables ?
For exemple in a boucle, i want to declare as many variables as the number of rounds done by the boucle :

```
DECLARE y INT DEFAULT 1;
WHILE y <= 5 DO
DECLARE CONCAT("var",y) CHAR(5);
SET y = Y+1;
END WHILE;
```

?
The need is to name it var1, in order to assign it a value later.
Thanks

Comment: What message did you get while executing the above ?

Comment: This can't work. why do you want so many variables?  too many vars will cause much resource consuming in the DB  server side.

Comment: What’s a Boucle?

Comment: No you cannot. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html says: "DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and **must be at its start, before any other statements.**" You cannot use DECLARE inside a WHILE loop.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should describe what you are trying to do that makes you think you need many variables, and then perhaps someone can suggest a different solution.